# How to set a keyspace for a query in nodejs cassandra driver?

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am trying to make a query with cassandra-driver, specifying the keyspace as an option, but am getting the error "No keyspace has been specified."

I am using the following code

```
connection = new driver.Client({ contactPoints: ['abc'] });

connection.execute(query, { keyspace: 'system_schema' })
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify keyspace as option to the `Client`, in your case it should be as following:

```
connection = new driver.Client({contactPoints: ['abc'], keyspace: 'system_schema'});
connection.execute(query, queryOptions, callback);
```

See documentation on [ClientOptions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-nodejs-driver-api/global.html#ClientOptions) & [QueryOptions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-nodejs-driver-api/global.html#QueryOptions).

If you need to access table in another namespace, then you need to use fully qualified table name in the query - as `keyspace_name.table_name`

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but what I need is to perform several queries on the same client for different keyspaces. In the DataStax documentation, they say to "Only use one Client instance per keyspace or use a single Client and explicitly specify the keyspace in your queries and reuse it in across your modules in the application lifetime", which is why I believe it should be somehow possible.

Comment: They are referring to explicit use of key space together with table name, so you need to modify your query to `select * from ks_name.table_name`